# Good thread for tying meat

Tags: equipment, meat, polish-cuisine, russian-cuisine

I want to prepare [*kotlet de volaille*](https://www.google.pl/search?q=de%20volaille&hl=pl&prmd=imvnse&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9nJhULSfLIWLswb72YDYBQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1304&bih=683). It'a a bit like Cordon Bleu, but using the natural pocket in chicken breast, and inside is just butter and fresh herbs.

I thought about tying the meat with a thread, like a roulade, but I've never done this before, so I don't know what kind of thread to use. Is there a special kind of thread of will my polyester sewing thread be enough?

*It took me some time, but I found the name of the dish in English - Chicken Kiev.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something more delicate than kitchen twine, any thread from a 100% natural fibre (cotton, hemp) should work.  Synthetics (polyester, rayon, nylon) could melt or offgas into your food when subject to high temperature.

Comment: Also beware colored thread, especially if its not designed for food use—the dies may leach out (and could be toxic).

Answer (score 5):

Don't use polyester, use [kitchen twine](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-kitchen-twine.htm) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Unflavored dental floss (the traditional kind, not the glide version) can be used and is finer than the kitchen twine.

Toothpicks can also be used to close the pocket and may actually be a little easier to remove than thread.

Best of luck with your dish!

Comment: Thank you, It wasn't as good as in a restaurant, but it was ok. I think I'll go with the toothpicks next time.

Comment: At least in Germany, dental floss generally is made from nylon, which could easily melt into the meat. Toothpicks should work though, and there are also specialized stainless steel skewers that are marketed as "roulade needles" here.